# Como Utilizar dois *ngFor ao mesmo tempo no Ionic2-framework

Tags: ionic, ionic2, angular

Estou tentando utilizar 2 *ngFor no mesmo ion-row. Primeiro tentei da seguinte forma:

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let mes of meses" *ngFor="let por of arrayPorc">
  <ion-col width-25>{{mes}}</ion-col>
  <ion-col width-25>{{por}}</ion-col>
  <ion-col width-25></ion-col>
  <ion-col width-25></ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Depois tentei dessa forma:

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let mes of meses;let por of arrayPorc">
  <ion-col width-25>{{mes}}</ion-col>
  <ion-col width-25>{{por}}</ion-col>
  <ion-col width-25></ion-col>
  <ion-col width-25></ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Em nenhuma das duas maneiras eu consegui exibir os valores calculados no TypeScript. Observação. Testei individualmente os arrays e eles estão funcionando. 
A única questão é como exibir dois arrays com *ngFor no mesmo ion-row.

Tem como?

Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Tenta colocar *ngFor="let mes of meses | let por of arrayPorc"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caso seus dois arrays sejam do mesmo tamanho, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let mes of meses; let i = index">
  <ion-col width-25>{{mes}}</ion-col>
  <ion-col width-25>{{arrayPorc[i]}}</ion-col>
  <ion-col width-25></ion-col>
  <ion-col width-25></ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Mas só vai funcionar se os dois arrays tiverem a mesma quantidade de elementos.

Comment: Muito obrigado Marlon! Na verdade eu precisava exibir 4 arrays com resultados de calculo de uma planilha de custos financeiros. Todos funcionaram com a tua dica. Obrigado Mesmo!

Comment: @TCury De nada! :-)